# Why does tkinter.ttk Combobox clear displayed value on initial selection only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, tkinter, ttk

I am building a gui in tkinter and I am seeing a curious behaviour for a `ttk.Combobox`.  Everything initializes fine, but when I select an item from the dropdown, the combobox display clears.  This only happens the first time I make a selection.  So I start the app > make a selection > **display clears** > make another selection > diplays normal.  Here's the code (only pertinent parts for brevity).  The combobox class fetches a column from a database as a list and assigns that to the values.  Otherwise, it is pretty straighforward tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import N, S, E, W
from tkinter import END, CENTER

import dbmanager


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):

    """Main GUI class for EngCalc."""

    def __init__(self, db_mngr):
        """See class docstring."""
        self.db = db_mngr
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'EngCalc')
        self.init_root_frame(master=self)

    def init_root_frame(self, master=None):
        """Create and initialize main GUI container."""
        self.root_frame = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.root_frame.grid()

        DBCombo(master=self.root_frame, controller=self,
                table='[Materials(SI)]', col='Material')


class DBCombo(ttk.Combobox):

    """A dropdown combobox for a given column in database table."""

    def __init__(self, master=None, controller=None,
                 table=None, col=None, row=0, column=0):
        """See class docstring."""
        self.values = controller.db.fetch_list(table, col)
        self.combovar = tk.StringVar()
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, master, values=self.values,
                              textvariable=self.combovar)
        self.current(0)
        self.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.newselection)
        self.grid(column=column, row=row)
        self.state(['!disabled', 'readonly'])

    def newselection(self, event):
        """Get value of combobox."""
        self.combovar = self.get()
        print(self.combovar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = '../db/test1.sqlite'
    database = dbmanager.DatabaseManager(db)
    foo = MainGUI(database)
    foo.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At one point in your code `self.combovar` points to an instance of a `StringVar`, but later you redefine `self.combovar` to be a string. The solution is to *not* redefine `self.combovar` inside `newselection`

Comment: Thanks Bryan... rookie mistake.  Is there any advantage to performing the `get()` on the `ComboBox` vs performing it on the `StringVar()`?

Comment: @ChristopherPearson: no, there is no advantage.